# If Else statement isn't working properly

Tags: php, mysql

So it has been a few days, and i still can't get it to work properly

On the website i got this in the code:

```
<?php
                    include ('function.php');
                       echo countUser('ko');
                                                  ?>
```

And I'm using this function to count how many 'ko' there are.
If there's more than 5, then it should say "There is no available space left"
But if there's 2 'ko' then i want the ELSE to say "there are 3 spaces left"

So here's my code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("cursussite");

function countUser ($cursus)
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Totalcursus FROM cursisten WHERE cursus = '".$cursus."' ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql)  or die (mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_row($query) or die (mysql_error());

    if ($data > 5){

        echo "Alle plaatsen zijn bezet.";


        }

    else {
        echo "Er zijn nog " .$data. " plaatsen beschikbaar";
    }
}


?>
```

I executed the code but i'm getting : Alle plaatsen zijn bezet. The weird
thing is that I only have two records in the database with 'ko'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$data` is an Array of Arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You are counting the wrong variable. `$data` will hold the current row fetched. Instead you should use this:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) or die (mysql_error());
$count = $data['Totalcursus'];

if ( $count > 5 ) {
    // ...
```

And the obvious addition: `mysql` extension is deprecated. Try migrating your code to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: `$data` is a way to loop over each row, not to get a single result.

Comment: `$data = mysql_fetch_row($query);` isn't that just the single row in an associative array? Not that fond of mysql functions myself, I use pdo.

Comment: It is for a single result if the query groups the data in a way that the result will be only one row (which the `COUNT(*)` statement effectively does). To put it in simple: there can be no more then one row as a result of this query. In procedural `mysql` API this is the only way to retrieve any data from the result set.

Comment: Cool, so we do learn something daily. I thought it was only one row, because if it was more than one, I would use mysql_fetch_array, and a while loop to loop through the data, if I was using mysql of course.